# Azure Ad b2c - Unable to see Phone details in the users MFA methods

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using phone MFA for the users. I added steps as per the code samples given here.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone

I see it is working as expected but I don't see the phone getting added under "Authentication Methods"(like Software OATH token).

Where exactly it is getting saved and what could be done to add it to the user's "Authentication Methods"?

[image]

Comment: You can make use of **Microsoft Graph** API to add phone method as Authentication method of Azure AD B2C user.

Comment: @Sridevi: Thanks for your response. Yes, I can add the Phone method as an Authentication method using Graph API, but my question is - since I followed the solutions/custom policies from the above example, 1. where this phone number is getting saved(definitely not under Authentication methods) and 2. what could be done to add it to Authentication methods from custom policies(technical profile)?

Answer (score 0):

By default, it will be stored in the `identities` collection for the user with `"signInType": "phoneNumber"`.

Additionally, you can store it in Authentication methods by adding it to the persisted claims as

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonPhoneNumber">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">You are already registered, please press the back button and sign in instead.</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.phoneNumber" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.phoneNumber" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <!-- Add sign-in phone number to authentication methods -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.phoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hasFullProfile" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.phoneNumber" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Note, authentication methods should only be used for MFA challenges and not generically storing phone numbers of users. Consider using extension attributes depending on your use case.

There is currently a bug with Azure AD B2C adding phone numbers to the authentication methods where it will initially show up blank in the portal and via graph API. I have not found a workaround to this.

Comment: Is there any docs for "it will be stored in the identities collection for the user"? I wrote `strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber` via policy, and its remembered for subsequent logins, and I can see the number in Authentication methods in the b2c portal (after switching back to the old view), but I do not see the entry present in `identities` when calling `Get-MgUser`. Does your last paragraph imply it's not possible to see the entry at all in MsGraph?